# Is this a lettuce?

Tags: identification

A few of these have popped up this year in and around my greenhouse near Mainz, Germany. From googling, it looks to me like an "All the Year Round Lettuce", which I've never planted. Leaves are currently about 10-20cm long. Much obliged if anyone can confirm exactly what it is.

[image: top view]

[image: side view]

Comment: There are many varieties of lettuces and pollination cannot be controlled on our gardens, so every plant, which it come from our seeds, is hybrids. Maybe it is also better then original one, but not stable, so the seeds of such new plant (also with controlled pollination) will form an other "variety".

Comment: I don't think lettuces cross that easily, and I grow very little if any in a given year. But I guess it's possible.

Comment: @decuria: why not? Usually we have various varieties of lettuces, and they flower for very long period. Near gardens we see often such "wild" lettuces in flower (and we have BTW also wild lettuces).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi yes, you're right: according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lettuce#Cultivation) "Lettuce will also cross with Lactuca serriola (wild lettuce), with the resulting seeds often producing a plant with tough, bitter leaves." Well, I tried it and the leaves are slightly tough, but not bitter. Tastes like... lettuce!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colours don't look quite right to me but sessile leaves (attached direct to the trunk) with a relatively very strong midrib (slightly U-shaped in cross-section) from which the two sides fold slightly towards one another looks lettuce-like. However for me it is the stalk that is most convincing. That is not shown in this image of a [Jericho](http://forums2.gardenweb.com/discussions/1466866/when-to-harvest-romaine-lettuce):

[image: lettuce]

but that bend looks *very* familiar (perhaps from planting too shallow or in a windy environment).

Yes, it is a lettuce.

Comment: Thanks @pnuts. The stalk is also what had me thinking it must be a lettuce. I nibbled on a leaf and it's a bit tough but not bitter. Perhaps I'll let it go to flower, just to see.

Comment: No rabbits around here, fortunately. As for slugs, we had a very dry spring. No rain from the end of February to until about three weeks ago. Also, it's growing inside my new greenhouse, which I built over an existing bed before winter. Presumably the seed was already present. It's kept watered because it's right beside a cucumber that I planted (you can make out the leaves in the photo, to the right), but otherwise no special attention.